# Https Redirect infinite loop in Mobile browsers

Tags: htaccess, ssl, https, mobile

I have recently installed SSL on my website and made some changes in htaccess to rewrite http to https routes.

It is working perfectly fine in desktop browsers but not in Mobile browsers. Not sure why.

Here is my htaccess details:-

```
 # BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

# mobile specific configuration starts
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} android|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge\ |maemo|midp|mmp|opera\ m(ob|in)i|palm(\ os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows\ (ce|phone)|xda|xiino [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a\ wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r\ |s\ )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1\ u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp(\ i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-|\ |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac(\ |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt(\ |\/)|klon|kpt\ |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg(\ g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-|\ |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v\ )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v\ )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-|\ )|webc|whit|wi(g\ |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 
# configuration ends 

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] </IfModule> 
# END WordPress
```

I have even tried to use some Mobile specific instructions which you can see above. But that is also not working.

**Note :**  URL is same for both Mobile and non-mobile users. (i.e. : https://www.example.com)

Please help.

Comment: Is this your entire Apache file? You might have gotten better results with serverfault, why are you handling mobile devices differently from desktops?

Comment: @TomJNowell This is the . htaccess file located in root directory of my WordPress site (with shared hosting). Initially I didn't have mobile specific instructions because I thought it would work in all the browsers irrespective of platform. But it didn't. So I had to add mobile specific instructions to see if it works.

Comment: What directives did you have before the "mobile specific" directives that worked OK on desktop? (The current directives won't do anything on desktop browser.) How is the SSL managed for your site?

Comment: @MrWhite I am considering  HTTP_USER_AGENT instructions as mobile specific instructions. However, redirection is working in desktop in both cases (with mobile and/or without mobile based directives)

Comment: You were initially correct, it **should** not need mobile specific directives

Comment: When testing on mobile, are you connecting to WiFi or mobile network? Have you tried it on different mobiles and different networks?

Comment: @TomJNowell that is not working either.

Comment: @MrWhite tested it in both mobile network and wifi and in 3 other mobile devices. Same result - too many redirects. So weird it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my cloudfare settings, i found that SSL encryption over cloudfare was "off". I turned it to "Full Strict"..  Then the problem was fixed.  But i am still not sure why i was getting redirect loop in mobile browsers only.